# What happens to the thread affinity of a QObject created within a worker thread which then terminates?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtconcurrent

Let's say I call `QtConcurrent::run()` which runs a function in a worker thread, and in that function I dynamically allocate several QObjects (for later use). Since they were created in the worker thread, their thread affinity should be that of the worker thread. However, once the worker thread terminates, the QObject thread affinity should no longer be valid.

The question: Does Qt automatically move the QObjects into the parent thread, or are *we* responsible in moving them to a valid thread before the worker thread terminates?

Comment: This is a good question. Did you test it the way @Troubadour suggested?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`QThread` is not documented to automatically move any `QObject`s when it finishes, so I think we can already conclude that it does no such thing. Such behavior would be very surprising, and at odds with the rest of the API.

Just for completeness, I tested with Qt 5.6:

```
QObject o;
{
    QThread t;
    o.moveToThread(&t);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        t.start();
        QVERIFY(t.isRunning());
        QVERIFY(o.thread() == &t);
        t.quit();
        t.wait();
        QVERIFY(t.isFinished());
        QVERIFY(o.thread() == &t);
    }
}
QVERIFY(o.thread() == nullptr);
```

Recall that a `QThread` is not a thread, it *manages* a thread.

When a `QThread` finishes, it continues to exist, and the objects that live in it continue to live in it, but they no longer process events. The `QThread` can be restarted (not recommended), at which point event processing will resume (so the same `QThread` could then be managing a different thread).

When a `QThread` is destroyed, the objects that lived in it cease to have any thread affinity. The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#qobject-reentrancy) doesn't guarantee this, and in fact says *"You must ensure that all objects created in a thread are deleted before you delete the `QThread`."*

---

> Let's say I call `QtConcurrent::run()` which runs a function in a worker thread, and in that function I dynamically allocate several QObjects (for later use). Since they were created in the worker thread, their thread affinity should be that of the worker thread. However, once the worker thread terminates, the QObject thread affinity should no longer be valid.

The `QThread` does not terminate in this scenario. When a task spawned by `QtConcurrent::run` finishes, the `QThread` it was running in is returned to the `QThreadPool` and may be reused by a subsequent call to `QtConcurrent::run`, and `QObject`s living in that `QThread` continue to live there.

```
QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(1);
QObject *o = nullptr;
QThread *t = nullptr;
QFuture<void> f = QtConcurrent::run([&] {
    o = new QObject;
    t = o->thread();
    QVERIFY(t == QThread::currentThread());
});
f.waitForFinished();
QVERIFY(t == o->thread());
QVERIFY(t->isRunning());
f = QtConcurrent::run([=] {
    QVERIFY(t == QThread::currentThread());
});
f.waitForFinished();
```

You might want to manually move an object out of a `QThread` before it is returned to the `QThreadPool`, or just don't use `QtConcurrent::run`. Having a `QtConcurrent::run` task construct `QObject`s which outlive the task is a questionable design, tasks should be self-contained. As noted by @Mike, the `QThread`s used by `QtConcurrent::run` do not have event loops.

Comment: "When a QThread is destroyed, the objects that lived in it cease to have any thread affinity." - is this documented anywhere in the docs? If it is documented, does this mean that as long as the `QThread` object exists but its thread has stopped, I am not allowed to delete the object (since objects can only be deleted in the thread of their affinity), but afterwards I can delete the object?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Actually the docs say we shouldn't leave objects living in a deleted `QObject`, so I've edited my answer. About deleting objects: objects [can be deleted](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#per-thread-event-loop) from outside the thread of their affinity, provided you can guarantee they are not currently processing events, which they won't be if the `QThread` has finished. But the usual way is to connect `QThread::finished` to `QObject::deleteLater`.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. The text you linked to clarifies it. And the text in the docs of `~QObject` is misleading, as it says "You must not delete the QObject directly if it exists in a different thread than the one currently executing. ".

Answer (score 5):

> However, once the worker thread terminates, the QObject thread affinity should no longer be valid.

The worker thread does **NOT** terminate after your function call. The whole point of using [`QtConcurrent::run`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html) is executing a large number of small tasks on the global thread pool (or some provided `QThreadPool`) while [re-using threads](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html#qthreadpool-and-qrunnable-reusing-threads) to avoid the overhead of creating and destroying threads for each one of these small tasks. In addition to distributing computation across all available cores.

You can try looking at the source code for Qt to see [how `QtConcurrent::run` is implemented](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/concurrent/qtconcurrentrun.h#n71). You will see that it ends up calling [`RunFunctionTaskBase::start`](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/concurrent/qtconcurrentrunbase.h#n81), which essentially calls [`QThreadPool::start`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html#start) with a `QRunnable` that calls the function that was passed initially to `QtConcurrent::run`.

Now the point that I want to get to is that, `QThreadPool::start` is [implemented](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/thread/qthreadpool.cpp#n455) by adding the `QRunnable` to a queue, and then trying to wake up one of the threads from the thread pool (which are [waiting](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/thread/qthreadpool.cpp#n133) for a new `QRunnable` to be added to the queue). The thing to note here, is that threads from the thread pool are not running an event loop (they are not designed to act this way), they are there just to execute `QRunnable`s in the queue and nothing more (they are implemented this way for performance reasons obviously).

This means that, the moment you are creating a `QObject` in a function executed in `QtConcurrent::run`, you are just creating a `QObject` that lives in a thread with no event-loop, from the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#per-thread-event-loop), restrictions include:

> If no event loop is running, events won't be delivered to the object. For example, if you create a `QTimer` object in a thread but never call `exec()`, the `QTimer` will never emit its `timeout()` signal. Calling `deleteLater()` won't work either. (These restrictions apply to the main thread as well.)

---

**TL;DR:** `QtConcurrent::run` runs functions in threads from the global `QThreadPool` (or a provided one). Those threads do not run an event loop, They just wait for `QRunnable`s to run. So, a `QObject` living in a thread from these threads doesn't get any events delivered.

---

In the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html#comparison-of-solutions), They have put using [`QThread` (possibly, with an event loop and a worker object)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html#qthread-low-level-api-with-optional-event-loops) and using [`QtConcurrent::run`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html#qt-concurrent-using-a-high-level-api) as two separate multi-threading technologies. They are not meant to be mixed together. So, **no worker objects in thread pools**, this is just asking for trouble.

> The question: Does Qt automatically move the QObjects into the parent thread, or are we responsible in moving them to a valid thread before the worker thread terminates?

I think that after looking at things this way, The answer is obvious that Qt does **NOT** move `QObject`s into any thread automatically. The documentation has warned about using a `QObject` in a `QThread` without an event loop, and that's it.

You are free to move them to whatever thread you like. But please keep in mind that [`moveToThread()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) can sometimes cause problems. For example, if moving your worker object involves moving a `QTimer`:

> Note that all active timers for the object will be reset. The timers are first stopped in the current thread and restarted (with the same interval) in the targetThread. As a result, constantly moving an object between threads can postpone timer events indefinitely.

---

**Conclusion:** I think that you should consider using your own `QThread` that runs its event loop, and create your worker `QObject`s there instead of using `QtConcurrent`. This way is far better than moving `QObject`s around, and can avoid many errors that can arise from using your current approach. Have a look at the [comparison table of multi-threading technologies in Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html#comparison-of-solutions) and choose the technology that best suits your use case. Only use `QtConcurrent` if you want to just execute a one-call function and get its return value. If you want permanent interaction with the thread, you should switch to using your own `QThread` with worker `QObject`s.

Answer (score 3):

> Does Qt automatically move the QObjects into the parent thread, or are we responsible in moving them to a valid thread before the worker thread terminates?

**No**, Qt doesn't automatically move `QObject` into the parent thread.

This behavior doesn't explicitly documented, so I've done a small investigation of the Qt framework [source code](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib), master branch.

`QThread` starts in [`QThreadPrivate::start`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/thread/qthread_win.cpp):

```
unsigned int __stdcall QT_ENSURE_STACK_ALIGNED_FOR_SSE QThreadPrivate::start(void *arg)
{

  ...

  thr->run();

  finish(arg);
  return 0;
}
```

[`QThread::terminate()`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/thread/qthread_win.cpp) implementation:

```
void QThread::terminate()
{
  Q_D(QThread);
  QMutexLocker locker(&d->mutex);
  if (!d->running)
      return;
  if (!d->terminationEnabled) {
      d->terminatePending = true;
      return;
  }
  TerminateThread(d->handle, 0);
  d->terminated = true;
  QThreadPrivate::finish(this, false);
}
```

In both cases thread finalization is done in [`QThreadPrivate::finish`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/thread/qthread_win.cpp):

```
void QThreadPrivate::finish(void *arg, bool lockAnyway)
{
  QThread *thr = reinterpret_cast<QThread *>(arg);
  QThreadPrivate *d = thr->d_func();

  QMutexLocker locker(lockAnyway ? &d->mutex : 0);
  d->isInFinish = true;
  d->priority = QThread::InheritPriority;
  bool terminated = d->terminated;
  void **tls_data = reinterpret_cast<void **>(&d->data->tls);
  locker.unlock();
  if (terminated)
      emit thr->terminated();
  emit thr->finished();
  QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents(0, QEvent::DeferredDelete);
  QThreadStorageData::finish(tls_data);
  locker.relock();

  d->terminated = false;

  QAbstractEventDispatcher *eventDispatcher = d->data->eventDispatcher;
  if (eventDispatcher) {
      d->data->eventDispatcher = 0;
      locker.unlock();
      eventDispatcher->closingDown();
      delete eventDispatcher;
      locker.relock();
  }

  d->running = false;
  d->finished = true;
  d->isInFinish = false;

  if (!d->waiters) {
      CloseHandle(d->handle);
      d->handle = 0;
  }

  d->id = 0;
}
```

It posts `QEvent::DeferredDelete` event to cleanup `QObject::deleteLater`, than TLS data cleaned up with `QThreadStorageData::finish(tls_data)` and `eventDispatcher` deleted. After that `QObject` will receive no events from this thread, but `QObject`'s thread affinity stays the same. It's interesting to see implementation of [`void QObject::moveToThread(QThread *targetThread)`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp) to understand how thread affinity changes.

Implementation of `void QThreadPrivate::finish(void *arg, bool lockAnyway)` makes clear that `QObject`'s thread affinity is not changed by `QThread`.

Comment: Hi @JohannesSchaub-litb, please review my investigation. I hope it will be helpful?

Comment: What about when a `QThread` is deleted? My investigation found that the `QObject`s that lived in it will satisfy `thread()==nullptr` but the docs suggest we shouldn't rely on this.

Comment: @Oktalist Right. [`~QThread`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/thread/qthread.cpp) sets `thread` field to `0` of it's `QThreadData` object at line `d->data->thread = 0;`. Because of it each `QObject` that lived in this thread will have `d->threadData->thread` equals to `0`. It means `thread() == nullptr`.

Comment: Thanks for your investigation. I would have liked to give both of you half of the bounty, but unfortunately that wasn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old question, I recently asked the same question, and just answered it using QT 4.8 and some testing.

AFAIK you cannot create objects with a parent from a QtConcurrent::run function.  I have tried the following two ways.  Let me define a code block then we will explore the behavior by selecting POINTER_TO_THREAD.

Some psuedo code will show you my test

```
Class MyClass : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  doWork(void)
  {
    QObject* myObj = new QObject(POINTER_TO_THREAD);
    ....
  }
}

void someEventHandler()
{
  MyClass* anInstance = new MyClass(this);
  QtConcurrent::run(&anInstance, &MyClass::doWork)
}
```

Ignoring potential scoping issues...

If `POINTER_TO_THREAD` is set to `this`, then you will get an error because `this` will resolve to a pointer to the `anInstance` object which lives in the main thread, *not* the thread QtConcurrent has dispatched for it.  You will see something like...

`Cannot create children for a parent in another thread.  Parent: anInstance, parents thread: QThread(xyz), currentThread(abc)`

If `POINTER_TO_THREAD` is set to `QObject::thread()`, then you will get an error because because it will resolve to the QThread object in which `anInstance` lives, and *not* the thread QtConcurrent has dispatched for it. You will see something like...

`Cannot create children for a parent in another thread.  Parent: QThread(xyz), parents thread: QThread(xyz), currentThread(abc)`

Hope my testing is of use to someone else.  If anyone knows a way to get a pointer to the QThread which QtConcurrent runs the method in, I would be interested to hear it!

Comment: You can use `QThread::currentThread()` in the your `doWork` function to get the `QThread` that `QtConcurrent` runs the method in. But I don't think this would be of any benefit since this `QThread` object lives in the main thread (you can't do something like `new QObject(QThread::currentThread());`).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if Qt automatically change the thread affinity. But even if it does, the only reasonable thread to move to is the main thread. I would push them at the end of the threaded function myself.

```
myObject->moveToThread(QApplication::instance()->thread());
```

Now this only matters if the objects make use of event process like send and receive signals.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know how to move an object into another thread, I'm just curious if we have to, and how Qt handles the above situation. Besides, you might want to move them to another thread besides the main thread. Having an explicit moveToThread call within a function would limit its reuse outside of this situation. I will try and make a wrapper class around `QtConcurrent::run()` to handle these things and see how that goes.

Answer (score 1):

Although the Qt docs don't appear to specify the behaviour you could find out by keeping track of what `QObject::thread()` returns before and after the thread finishes.