# Loading files into drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &)

Tags: file, qt, opengl, load

currently i am trying to laod *.obj-files into my programm. My code is based on this example:

[Accelerate your widgets with OpenGL(changed link)](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/modelviewer)

The only differeence in my code, is that i have a glwidget-class, in which all the drawing is defined. In the class OpenGLScene only my Gui is defined. In the function drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &) i call the function paintGL.

```
void OpenGLScene::drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &)
{
    if (painter->paintEngine()->type() != QPaintEngine::OpenGL
    && painter->paintEngine()->type() != QPaintEngine::OpenGL2)
{
    qWarning("OpenGLScene: drawBackground needs a QGLWidget to be set as viewport on the graphics view");
    return;
}

painter->beginNativePainting();

glClearColor(m_backgroundColor.redF(), m_backgroundColor.greenF(), m_backgroundColor.blueF(), 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

if (m_model) {

    m_model->paintGL();
}

painter->endNativePainting();
```

}

Simple drawing and stuff works fine. I only get problems until i try to load *.obj-Files. I have tried several things, which didnt work.
Now I ended up with the solution to define all the functions from the model-class(which you can find in the example) in my glWidget-Class and then calling the render-function in paintGL. Afterwards calling the paintGL in OpenGLScene.

Here you can see my header-files: OpenGLScene.h and GLWidget.h:

```
class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
float           m_distance;
GLWidget(const QString &filePath);
GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
~GLWidget();
QSize           minimumSizeHint() const;
QSize           sizeHint() const;
void            initializeGL();
void            paintGL();
void            resizeGL(int width, int height);
void render() const;
QString fileName() const { return m_fileName; }
int faces() const { return m_pointIndices.size() / 3; }
int edges() const { return m_edgeIndices.size() / 2; }
int points() const { return m_points.size(); }
QString m_fileName;
QVector<Point3d> m_points;
QVector<Point3d> m_normals;
QVector<int> m_edgeIndices;
QVector<int> m_pointIndices;
};


#ifndef QT_NO_CONCURRENT
#include <QFutureWatcher>
#endif

class GLWidget;

class OpenGLScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
OpenGLScene();
void drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect);
QDialog *createDialog(const QString &windowTitle) const;

void setModel(GLWidget *model);

//Model       *m_model;
GLWidget    *m_model;
QColor      m_backgroundColor;
float       m_distance;
QLabel      *m_labels[4];
QWidget     *m_modelButton;
#ifndef QT_NO_CONCURRENT
QFutureWatcher<GLWidget *> m_modelLoader;
#endif
public slots:
void loadModel();
void loadModel(const QString &filePath);
void modelLoaded();
};
```

Unfortunately this idea isnt working, because i get this error:

"It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread"

But I really dont understand whats that supposed to mean.

Comment: Hm…Maybe I should specify it more.

My first question would be why it is a problem to define the modelfunctions in glwidget?
GLWidget’s content is the same as the model-class content plus some extras.
Therefore I dont understand the error: “It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread”

Because in the OpenGLScene-Class I have nothing changed except the datatype-names. I’ve replaced Model-datatype to GLWidget-datatype.

Maybe someone would be able to help me? Or is it so obvious that it is to easy to answer. If so I would be happy if you could share your ideas with me.

Comment: For all of you who have maybe tried the code from the upper link. I am sorry but this is an old version which is not working. Here is the [new one](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/modelviewer) Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've moved all the `Model` stuff into `GLWidget` then I assume you are now creating your `GLWidget` instance in `::loadModel`? If so then be aware that this is being created in a new thread. It looks like it doesn't automatically get moved into the main (GUI) thread when the loading thread finishes. What actually happens to the QObject is [an open question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383296/what-happens-to-the-thread-affinity-of-a-qobject-created-within-a-worker-thread/8957696#8957696).

If you want to disable threading completely in order to simplify things then remove the lines

```
#ifndef QT_NO_CONCURRENT
#include <QFutureWatcher>
#endif
```

and

```
#ifndef QT_NO_CONCURRENT
QFutureWatcher<Model *> m_modelLoader;
#endif
```

in openglscene.h. In the OpenGLScene constructor body remove the lines

```
#ifndef QT_NO_CONCURRENT
    connect(&m_modelLoader, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(modelLoaded()));
#endif
```

In `OpenGLScene::loadModel(const QString &filePath)` change

```
#ifndef QT_NO_CONCURRENT
    m_modelLoader.setFuture(QtConcurrent::run(::loadModel, filePath));
#else
    setModel(::loadModel(filePath));
    modelLoaded();
#endif
```

to just

```
    setModel(::loadModel(filePath));
    modelLoaded();
```

Finally remove

```
#ifndef QT_NO_CONCURRENT
    setModel(m_modelLoader.result());
#endif
```

from `OpenGLScene::modelLoaded()`.

Comment: Well, as I understand it, it is not possible to load obj-files as I tried to do. I have tried to push my object into the main-thread but it isnt working. I am a complete newbie to threading. I have researched a little bit on this matter, but I cant get a grip on this. The whole concept of threading seems to be a BIG thing. Might there be another way to load obj.-files? Maybe without threading. From your answer I get the feeling that there might be a possibility. Could you be more specific? Thank you.

Comment: @buddy: You can certainly remove the threading easily enough as there are two code paths wherever the threading is used. Which one is compiled in is dependent on the QT_NO_CONCURRENT preprocessor macro. Either ensure that this macro is defined at the top of the relevant source files or just comment out the threading code (which is in the `ifndef QT_NO_CONCURRENT` bits). Try this and see if it works. If you want to get it working with threading let me know and I can see what I can do.

Comment: Actually Qt seem to have another problem.I have removed the threading from the unchanged sourcecode.(Where i still have the model class).This is working fine. As soon as I add to the Model class `: public QGLWidget` I get the error: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread. So it seems to be rather the inheritance in general than the threading. And the inheritance I need in GLWidget Do you know why that might be?

Comment: @buddy: I've updated my answer to outline everything you need to do to ensure you are not threading. Check that you have made all of these changes.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I had to work the last days. Thank you for your help, it works now. I am not getting why threads should be used, if it is working fine this way. But maybe someday I will start to learn the whole thread-thing. Maybe then it will make sense. Thanks again

Comment: @buddy: The reason for using threading in this case is to allow the model loading to happen in the background i.e. without freezing the GUI.